# Alter the CSS of the first p tag after each H4 tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a stylesheet which indents paragraphs by 20px, but I do not want an indent on the first paragraph after each H4.

So I have something like this:

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<h4>Sub Heading</h4>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
```

Using jquery I want to override the css on Paragraph 3 so there is no text-indent.

I tried this but nothing happened:

```
$("#myDiv > h4").next("p").css({"text-indent":0});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with just CSS:

```
#myDiv > h4 + p {
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

That selector means: select `p` preceded by `h4` that is a child of `#myDiv`.

`+` is the [adjacent sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector).

Or as JavaScript if you prefer:

```
$('#myDiv > h4 + p').css('text-indent', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [this](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_adjacent.htm)?

Use `h4 + p` as your selector.

Answer (score 0):

many ways are there...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myDiv h4').each(function(){
    $(this).next().css({"text-indent":0});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ijexij/2/edit)

```
$('#myDiv h4').next('p').css({textIndent:0});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#myDiv > h4:first-child")css({"text-indent":0});
```

http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/